# Django: include html saved as string in template rendering

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I build an HTML table in my `views.py` function and I want to include it in a template that I already have when rendering. I see that the `div` is created, but the HTML table is not created. What is the problem?

this is the line in `views.py`:

`render(request, 'aztracker/import_data.html', {'my_html':html_data})`
where html_data is like

```
"<table><tr><th>column1</th></tr><tr><td>data1</td></tr> ....</table>"
```

and I have this section in my `import_data.html`:

```
    <div class="bootstrap-iso">
        <div class="tbl_container_numbers">
            {{ my_html }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is the sanme div after rendering:

```
    <div class="bootstrap-iso">
        <div class="tbl_container_numbers">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your question doesn't really show what the problem is. Your `render()` call includes `my_html` in the context, so `{{ my_html }}` in the template should work.

Comment: It does not give any error, but the html table (my_html) does not appear too

Comment: There's not enough information in the question to reproduce the problem so we can't help.

Comment: what else do you need?

Comment: do you need `{{ my_html|safe }}` ?

Comment: `{{ my_html|safe }}` did not work too

Comment: you should tell us what do you see in the rendered source code

Comment: when I use `return HttpResponse(html_data)` to make sure that html table is constructed correctly, I get the table rendered, now I just want to include this in a template. Let me add the whole template to see if it helps

Comment: if you show the complete view it might show where the problem is.

Comment: I added the `views.py` too

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. To render an html code stored as a string we should use the built-in autoescape tag:

```
    <div class="bootstrap-iso>
        <div class="tbl_container_numbers">
            {% autoescape off %}
                {{ my_html }}
            {% endautoescape %}
        </div>
    </div>
```